# Rotate table based on drop down input

Tags: arrays, sorting, if-statement, google-sheets, transpose

### Data

I have a table `B3:F7` with a changing range, more or less rows and columns.

### Objective

I want to **Rotate** the **original table** using the input from the drop down `I2:M2` to get the result like  90, 180, 270 Rotation.

### To clarify

- **I don't want to choose between** them; I want the original table to be Rotated according to the input of the dropdown. I have only the original table and the data is mixed and the range is growing.
- The formatting is for demonstration only.

### Progress

I tried transpose twice `=TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(B3:F7))` to get 180 result, but the output is reverted back to the original form `B3:F7`.

### Sources

[**Make a copy**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HOwKELnmfpX3NJO91cD1EPb2s0aKCY9rnYss0nIKVlU/copy)

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I2=O3, B3:F7, 
 IF(I2=O4, TRANSPOSE(SORT(B3:F7, ROW(B3:F7), 0)),
 IF(I2=O5, TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SORT(B3:F7, ROW(B3:F7), 0)), ROW(B3:F7), 0)),
 IF(I2=O6, SORT(TRANSPOSE(B3:F7), ROW(B3:F7), 0), )))))
```

[image]